# How can "git gui" open repository from parent directory?

Tags: command-line, gnome, scripts, git

I start Git GUI tool using command `git gui` or `git citool`.

I wanted to add **another entry to right click script menu** (already have dozens of commands) and created a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git citool $1
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
git gui $1
```

but any of these opens a blank Git GUI

[image]

This **does not happen** if I open the Terminal and run `git gui` from it.

Where am I making a mistake? Dozens of other apps work with the same parameter `$1`. Could it be that extra parameter `gui` or `citool` is causing the error?!

Comment: @Danatela It's the same as `git citool` which is a GUI frontend of Git. I got it via `sudo apt-get install git-gui`

Comment: Hm it seems that `git gui` does not accept parameters.

Comment: Installed it. I think your script takes wrong directory. Try to run it from inside the directory that has `.git`.

Comment: @Danatela It works when I am in the dir. At least it works from shell. But I need it in Right Click Menu. I cannot make it work via right click.

Comment: I changed my answer and undeleted it. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suppose you wrote `script.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
git gui $1
```

Change it like

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd $1 && git gui
```

Using `&&` will prevent execution of `git gui` if something goes wrong.

Comment: The "ugly way" of navigating to directory first worked! Neither of us knows why git gui cannot be run from parent directory, but this works.

Comment: I think it is so designed. Sometimes developers don't forecast the ways their software will be used :)